# What is the meaning of "shoot" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following quotation has been taken from *The Mark on the Wall* by Virgina Woolf.

> Tumbling head over heels in the asphodel meadows like brown paper parcels pitched down a shoot in the post office!

What does *shoot* mean here?

Comment: It's a misspelling of *chute*. Or, at least, if anyone but Woolf had written it, I'd call it a misspelling.

Answer (score 5):

A *shoot* can be:

> : a narrow tube or passage that things and people go down or through
>     <sub>source: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chute</sub>

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/shoot?s=t) lists the following meanings under the origin and history of *shoot*:

> "young branch of a tree or plant," mid-15c., from shoot (v.). Also "heavy, sudden rush of water" (1610s); "artificial channel for water running down" (1707); "conduit for coal, etc." (1844).

So we can see that "shoot" was used with a relevant meaning ("conduit for coal, etc.") near the time that Woolf was writing.

The *shoot* spelling was eventually replaced by the French *chute* ("to fall") for this and related meanings, as can be seen at [Dictionary.com's entry for *chute*.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/chute?s=t)

Comment: *The Mark on the Wall* is a [short story](http://www.online-literature.com/virginia_woolf/855/) told in the first person, from a stream-of-consciousness perspective - Woolf may have meant to use *shoot* rather than *chute* to indicate the less formal dialect of the narrator's internal speech.